# Blackberry support multiple resolutions

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, screen

I need to design the UI for a blackberry app. This app should support multiple blackberry resolutions.

One way would be to check the screen_width and screen_height every time, and accordingly fetch images from the res folder. Is there any other more efficient, or a better method to do this? I will also need to do the same for font sizes, of text, according to screen size.

Please help me know the standard method to support multiple BB resolutions

Comment: If we are talking about legacy BB Java development, then I'm afraid no. Else if you are developing a WebWorks app, then regular web strategies apply.

Comment: Yes i am talking about legacy BB Java development. So how were these apps managed previously?

Comment: Well, you had to solve this problem by yourself, no built-in mechanism was provided like in Android. This has been asked here a few times, here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3496175/813951

Comment: Also refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8165145), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3024263), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3451738) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3024263).

Answer (score 3):

You can try, what I have tried in my applications without any issues so far.

> **Step 1:**
>
> Create a separate package like com.your_app_name.uiconfig which will
>   contain an abstract class say ModelConfig and different classes for
>   different resolutions like class BB83xxConfig for resolution 320x240
>   (width x height), class BB95xxConfig for resolution 360 x 480 (width x
>   height).
>
> **Step 2:**
>
> ModelConfig class will provide the concrete implementation of the
>   methods that will be common to all irrespective of the screen
>   resolutions and the declaration of abstract methods whose concrete
>   implementation will be provided in the respective classes based on the
>   screen resolution.
>
> **Step 3:** Make each and every class, that is implemented for particular resolution extend ModelConfig and provide concrete
>   implementation of methods as per requirement.
>
> **Step 4:** Use singleton pattern to get the instance of ModelConfig, so that it is intantiated only once and that instance is used
>   throughout.

**ModelConfig.java  (Just a sample)**

```
public abstract class ModelConfig {

private static ModelConfig modelConfig = null;

public static ModelConfig getConfig() {

    if (modelConfig == null) {

        if (DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().startsWith("83")) {
            modelConfig = new BB83xxConfig();
        } else if (DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().startsWith("85")) {
            // 85xx also has 360 x 240 same as 83xx device
            modelConfig = new BB83xxConfig();
        } else if (DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().startsWith("89")) {
            modelConfig = new BB89xxConfig();
        } else if (DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().startsWith("90")) {
            modelConfig = new BB90xxConfig();
        } else if (DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().startsWith("95")) {
            modelConfig = new BB95xxConfig();
        } else if (DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().startsWith("96")) {
            modelConfig = new BB96xxConfig();
        } else if (DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().startsWith("97")) {
            modelConfig = new BB97xxConfig();
        } else if (DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().startsWith("99")) {
            modelConfig = new BB99xxConfig();
        } else if (DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().startsWith("98")) {
            // 9800 also has 360 x 480 same as 95xx device
            modelConfig = new BB95xxConfig();
        }else {
            modelConfig = new DefaultConfig();
        }
    }

    return modelConfig;
}

// Font height for the default font used for the application.
public abstract int getApplicationFontHeight();

// Font height for the header label font.
public abstract int getHeaderLabelFontHeight();

// Height for the coloured background of Header.
public abstract int getHeaderBarHeight();

// Height for the individual row in the list.
public abstract int getCustomListRowHeight();   

public abstract int getStandardButtonWidth();

public abstract int getStandardLabelWidth();    

public abstract int getTitleFontHeight();   

// get Background colour for Header.
public int getHeaderBackgroundColor() {
    return 0x26406D;
}   

// get Bitmap showing Right Arrow.
public Bitmap getBitmapRightArrow() {
    return Bitmap.getBitmapResource("right_arrow.png");
}

// get Bitmap rounded black border for editfield.
public Bitmap getBitmapRoundedBorderEdit(){
    return Bitmap.getBitmapResource("rounded_border_black.png");
}

// get Bitmap rounded gray border and white background.
public Bitmap getBtmpRoundedBorderBgrnd(){
    return Bitmap.getBitmapResource("rounded_border_grey.png");
}

// get Bitmap rounded gray border and white background.
public Bitmap getBtmpTransparentBgrnd(){
    return Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img_transparent_background.png");
}

// get Bitmap showing down Arrow.
public Bitmap getBitmapDownArrow(){

    return Bitmap.getBitmapResource("down_arrow.png");
}   

}
```

**BB95xxConfig.java (just a sample)**

```
/*
 * Common resolution 360*480 pixels (width x height)
 */
public class BB95xxConfig extends ModelConfig {
    // Font height for the default font used for the application.
    // returns Desired height in pixels.
    public int getApplicationFontHeight() {
        return 18;
    }

    // Font height for the header label font.
    // returns Desired height in pixels.
    public int getHeaderLabelFontHeight() {
        return 20;
    }

    // returns Desired height in pixels for the header background.
    public int getHeaderBarHeight() {
        return Display.getHeight() / 10;
    }

    public int getCustomListRowHeight() {
        return 50;
    }   

    public int getStandardButtonWidth() {
        return 108;
    }

    public int getStandardLabelWidth() {
        return 150;
    }

    public int getTitleFontHeight() {
            return 11;
    }
}
```